# Jekyll inserting extra code when generating blog posts

Tags: post, jekyll

I'm creating my first Jekyll site. I try to include a blogging section which I'm copying from an existing non-Jekyll version, converting existing blog pages which were in hardcoded html.

I put my header, navigation, and footer html in _include files. And I merge those in a layout file that also includes {{ content }}

I erase the header, navigation, and footer from the old html file and I only include the body in the .markdown file for the post.

I was expecting the content of the markdown file to be included at the place of the {{ content }}... it does, however Jekyll also seems to include this before the {{ content }} content:

```
<div class="highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code>
```

so instead of seeing my own html generated, I see the "code" version of my html. Where does this extra code come from, and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 5):

> Where does this extra code come from..?

The extra code `<div class="highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight">` you see is a sign of syntax-highlighting.

Syntax-highlighting is rendered in **2 ways**:

- When you enclose a block of text within triple backticks and a language ```` ```ruby ````

  ````
  ```ruby
  def some_method
    # do something
  end
  ```
  ````

  becomes

  ```ruby
  def some_method
    # do something
  end
  ```

  (the above block will have the same *extra code* in the generated `index.html`)

---

- When you indent kramdown content by more than 4 spaces

  ```
        ## Heading 2

        Some Markdown text here.
        Lorem Ipsum [dolor](sit/amet/index.html)
  ```

  becomes an unrendered block of Markdown highlighted for language `plain-text`

  ```
  ## Heading 2

  Some Markdown text here.
  Lorem Ipsum [dolor](sit/amet/index.html)
  ```